# How to find href and pass to .load?

Tags: jquery, load

I have some code which performs an ajax load when a link in a div element is clicked.

I now want to make the entire div clickable but not sure how to get this working with the .load. I think I know what is going wrong, but I don't know how to fix it as I am new to jQuery - hoping someone can help.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="work">
    <img class="introPic" src="images/thumb.jpg" width="250" height="99" />
    <h3>
        <img class="arrow" src="images/arrow_open.gif" alt="&gt;" />
        <a class="titlelink" href="project2.html">Project 2</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="projectIntro">
        <p>This is some intro text for project 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pictures"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the complete code block as it stands now:

```
$('div.work').on('click',function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    return false;

    var parent = $(this).parents(".work");
    var content_holder = parent.children(".pictures");

    if (parent.hasClass("selected_work")) {
        close_other();
        return;
    }

    close_other();

    parent.addClass("selected_work");

    content_holder.load(this + " #ajaxContent", function() {

    });

    $('.selected_work img.arrow').attr("src", "images/arrow_close.gif");
});

function close_other() {
    var selected_work = $('.selected_work');

    selected_work.children('.pictures').empty();    
    $('.selected_work img.arrow').attr("src", "images/arrow_open.gif");
    selected_work.removeClass("selected_work")
}

$('div.work').click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 500);
});      
});
```

The first problem is that when the `div` is clicked, it finds the `href` of the anchor inside but loads it in a new window as opposed to in the current window as desired. I presume this is because of the `window.location` - it finds the link and goes there whereas I want it to find the link and pass it to the ajax load.

The second problem is that the variables are now wrong. While the code was correct when an anchor inside `.work` was clicked (and the selector was `$(.work a)`- `.work` was therefore the anchor's parent but that is no longer the case:

I don't need a parent any more as the parent (`.work`) is what I am now clicking on so I guess it becomes simply `$(this)` - therefore logically I want something like:

```
    var content_holder = $(this).children(".pictures");

    if $(this).hasClass("selected_work")) {
        close_other();
        return;
    }
```

but that has a syntax error so it can't be right...

Then

```
parent.addClass("selected_work");
```

should probably change to something like

```
$(this).addClass("selected_work");
```

I would really appreciate some help getting the passing of the href and the syntax right for this as I've been trying to get it working for 2 days now. A working example would be the icing on the cake. Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the HTML structure you have. It's hard to visualise which element is the parent, which the child etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `return false;` rest of your code doesn't execute. You can change hash with `location.hash`:

```
var lastPart = $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/');
var hash = lastPart[lastPart.length - 1];
```

- Get `href` attribute
- Split it with `/`
- Take the last part

You don't have to use `.parents()` because `$(this)` refers to `.work` so final code will be:

```
$('div.work a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
$('div.work').bind('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
        lastPart = href.split('/'),
        hash = lastPart[lastPart.length - 1];

    var $this = $(this);
    var content_holder = $this.children(".pictures");

    close_others($this);
    if ($this.hasClass("selected_work")) {
      return;
    }
    else {
      window.location.hash = hash;
      $this.addClass("selected_work");
    }

    content_holder.load(href + ' #ajaxContent');

    $this.find('img.arrow').attr("src", "images/arrow_close.gif");
});
function close_others($current) {
  $('.selected_work').not($current).removeClass("selected_work")
    .find('.pictures').empty().end()
    .find('img.arrow').prop("src", "images/arrow_open.gif");
}
```

Comment: OK thanks - I did try without that and it still doesn't work - I can change it to prevent default? - but I'm sure that's not the only problem...

Comment: Thanks, appreciate you taking the time to help - would you mind clarifying that? as my href is currently just an url and does not contain a hash part to split... and if it did contain a hash part, what would it be?

Comment: Sorry, I miss something. You don't have any hash in your `a` element. I'll update my code.

Comment: Sorry Emre, maybe I did something wrong but this is not working for me - the div is clickable and the arrow img changes but the content is not loading: http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclickemre.html

Comment: Updated my answer. Tried on your site with firebug. Everything seems fine. Can you try it?

Comment: Emre - still no luck I'm afraid - i feel it is very close though! - http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclickemre2.html

Comment: Updated again. `close_other` was missing. Added that and some other functionality.

Comment: OK - were getting there! Content is now loading - just 2 issues I think - first text gets much bigger when a div is clicked, and second (and more important), first .pictures div does not close when another is opened - thank you. http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclickemre3.html

Comment: Sorry Emre - my mistake - tried your code above rather than the one on jsfiddle. The only issue is I think it's loading the entire html file rather than the #ajaxContent div within it. http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclickemre4.html  In the original code it was  contentHolder.load(loadUrl + " #ajaxContent", function() {

Comment: Emre - thank you so much for your help - this is perfect! (although in this version you missed the scroll bit out from the previous version - but I put that back in so no problem). You're a star and your help and expertise is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry Emre - on checking again I see one thing is still missing in this version - a second click on the same .work div should close its child .pictures - first click opens, second click (or click on another .work div) closes - you had this working in the previous version.

Comment: Emre - by taking your previous version and then adding the .load(href + ' #ajaxContent' bit from this version it seems to work - not sure what other changes you made in this version as the code seems to have changed more than that - but it works! thanks once again.

Comment: Little optimizations. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood what you're after - when the parent `div` is clicked, the `.pictures` div should be filled with content loaded via AJAX from the URL in `.titlelink`?

If so, try this:

```
$("DIV.work").on("click", function() {
    // empty any open projects
    $(".selected_work .pictures").empty();

    var $parent = $(this);
    $parent.addClass("selected_work");

    var loadUrl = $(".titlelink", $parent).attr("href");
    var contentHolder = $(".pictures", $parent);
    contentHolder.load(loadUrl + " #ajaxContent", function() {
        $(this).find('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
            animSpeed:300,
            pauseTime:4000,
            controlNav:true,
            pauseOnHover:true //Stop animation while hovering
        });

        $('.selected_work img.arrow').attr("src", "images/arrow_close.gif");
     });
});

// this stops the default link behaviour from opening the new window
$("DIV.work A").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - I have tried this but I get a syntax error on the var this = $(this); line...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've fixed it.

Comment: This is great Rory thank you - almost perfect - the first click loads the content via ajax, but if then I click a second project, it loads normally in a new window... http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclickrory.html

Comment: How do you mean 'when you click a second project'?

Comment: If you check my link you will see list of projects (as per my HTML at the top x 10) - click on any project and content loads by ajax, then click on a different project and link loads in new window.

Comment: Sorry Rory - my mistake - what is happening is that if the div outside of the anchor is clicked, the ajax loads correctly, but if the anchor itself is clicked, it loads in a new page - I want the anchor click to act the same as the div click. Another issue is that I need the first .pictures to close when another is opened.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. I've edited my answer with the fixes.

Comment: Thank you so much Rory, this is great - just a couple of things - first I am getting a strange but consistent issue. If I load the page and click on the anchors of projects 1-5, the content loads in a new window (if I click on div outside anchor it loads in ajax). If I click on anchor of project 6+ it loads in ajax. Once one project has loaded in ajax, clicks on anchors 1-5 will load in ajax too! http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclickrory2.html

Comment: And the final things is the scroll to top of the window when a div is clicked. It doesn't happen on the first click after page load but does on every click thereafter...

Comment: That's an odd problem - you're probably best starting a new question for that as it's not really the same subject as this one.

Comment: OK will do - thank you so much for you help on this Rory - seriously appreciated!

Comment: One other thing strange thing I noticed about this version Rory is that if I click on the div.work outside the anchor - say on the thumbnail - which loads .pictures, then click on the thumbnail again to close it, the entire project (div.work) dissappears - by doing this on each project I can end up with a completely empty window!